# Interviewer Said I am Overqualified and He Vilified the Company

Tags: interviewing

I took an interview today, I was told the IT guy (external company), two weeks ago, had a very similar personality.

As soon as I finished the presentation of my resume, the interviewer asserted that I am far ahead of my competition (other candidates). Therefore, I am overqualified he said.

I said I am looking for a technical challenges, he said there will be none.

Then I said "sometimes people change their jobs for the environment, the surrounding people etc.". He said that the atmosphere here is ugly, and even, the HR lady, who seems happy with her job, is getting ready for resigning -- contradiction.

Comment: Sorry you went through this, but your questions reads more like a rant after a bad experience than a question.  That said, why would you NOT avoid the company?

Comment: The (resigning) HR made a good impression two weeks ago. Her speech contained an interest and that she wouldn't want me to be hired so that I would leave in 1 or 2 months because of relocation. Also, this job is supposed to offer me a better salary.

Comment: This tells me more about the interviewers lack of professionalism than the companies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may very well be the case that the interviewer fears you would actually make him redundant or surpass him in the company. And most likely, because the interview isn't his choice alone, he would have no way of directly rejecting you without some serious basis, so he hopes that you won't take the job instead.

Comment: Should I take the job or should I flee?

Comment: @HalfLife Only you can decide that.

Comment: I mean does it sound much trouble? or Is it going to be alright to compete with that interviewer (who is an external IT contractor).

Comment: @HalfLife You have to be the judge of that. Depending on where you are in your career you might or might not want to take the risk. Its a risk yet, but its not guaranteed to be bad.

Answer (score 11):

It's quite clear that the interviewer doesn't want you at the company. There are two possibilities: A. He is warning you that the company should be avoided. B. He is afraid that you are too much of a competition for him if you join the company. (Or possibility C, he promised the job to his nephew).

It's up to you to find out which one it is, but you will be aware that if you start there, there is at least one guy who doesn't want you to be there. Maybe there are more suitable companies.

Comment: "joint" should probably be "join". A joint is something else that I doubt you are referring to here. (I would make the edit, but don't have the rep to make "trivial" edits here.)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - I fixed it.  Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the interviewer was telling you to look elsewhere, whether it was due to the fact that he liked you and was warning you, or that he didn't like you and was pushing you out the door is irrelevant.

Either way it means "look elsewhere."

If he liked you and was warning you, then you should take his advice.

If he didn't like you and was making excuses, then there will be a miserable life for you if you ARE hired, and at least he, if not he and some allies will make sure of it.  You should see this as a HUGE red flag.

Either way, this is NOT a company you want to work for.

Comment: What did you mean when you mention "is irrelevant"?

Comment: @HalfLife Seems pretty clear to me that Richard means that no matter whether the interviewer was trying to warn you off, or push you away, doesn't change (Richard's) interpretation that this is likely not a company you'd want to work for. (Note: I'm not judging in this comment whether Richard is right or wrong in making such an assessment.)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling  Correct, that is my assessment.