# How can I side step inappropriate questions in an interview?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing

I participated in a [weird hiring process](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/63169/interviewer-said-i-am-overqualified-and-he-vilified-the-company), where the HR was warm and welcoming, but two weeks later, I faced this IT guy who was supposed to assess my technical skills.

I realized this guy was inciting me to avoid the company because he was afraid of competition or some other reasons.

The problem is that this guy was telling me how horrific this company is, and then asked me what are my expectations in terms of salary.

Over analyzing the subject, my conclusion was that this guy was more collecting elements to use, either against me with the company, or against the company with me.

So my question is when this or other questions that are inappropriate for the interview are asked how can I side step them with out being combative or accusatory to the interviewer?

Comment: No matter what interpretation you give to the interviewer telling you how dreadful the company is, why on earth would you still want to work for them? Either the company really is terrible or you'll have *at least one* terrible coworker. (VTC as the title question is too broad and therefore doesn't match the body, needs clarification.)

Comment: My question is how to deal with such cases. I went through details just as a depiction of the circumstances I faced. I feel guilt having answered while it was none of his business ...

Comment: How do you know this question was out of scope? Not every company is going to have a strict demarcation where *only* the HR person talks about anything salary related, and the IT person *only* talks about your technical skills. He may have been expected to find out whether your skills matched your expectations.

Comment: Your first four paragraphs seem to have no bearing on the question.

Comment: `My question is how to deal with such cases.` You walk away.

Comment: @Lilienthal - There may be smaller companies that have a 100% staff approval rating, but I've never worked at a company that didn't have at least one person who hated it. Some had valid reasons, many of them were just miserable people who just wanted a paycheck.

Comment: @JeffO There is a difference between being unhappy and warning potential hires of the problems they'll face (which is rare but a good thing: some people like a chaotic work environment for instance) and someone actively discouraging new hires with horror stories. The latter is simply incredibly unprofessional and is a huge red flag.

Comment: "asked me what are my expectations in terms of salary" - is this the question you were trying to avoid answering? If so, there are threads on this topic. By the way, asking a potential employee about salary expectations is *not* "inappropriate"

Comment: @Brandin, I understand but the interviewer was malicious ... and was supposed to ask me "what are you going to bring to this company?" instead of getting into how much do you want?

Comment: @HalfLife: who told you that was supposed to be the question?

Comment: @jmoreno what do you mean?

Comment: @HalfLife: in some companies interviewers have a set list of questions they are suppoosed to ask, in others they can ask whatever they like.  You appear to think this company limits the questions and that this question wasn't on the list of questions this interviewer was allowed to ask.  Why do you believe that? Put another way, why do you think that was an inappropriate question for **this** interviewer? It's certainly a fairly standard interview question.

Comment: Well, this was a second interview. The primary one was with HR, who assessed my psychological profile as well as the salary and such. Whereas in the second interview, the IT guy didn't ask me anything technical, therefore, for me, he was looking for elements to use against me: he asked about the current salary and my salary, after inciting me to forget about the company.

Answer (score 15):

> How can I side step inappropriate questions in an interview?

*"**Why do you ask?**"*

This works for the vast majority of questions that you consider inappropriate or strange, no matter if it's coming from an interviewer or \a nosy colleague [prying into your personal affairs](http://www.askamanager.org/2012/07/my-coworker-is-creeping-me-out-but-i-dont-know-why.html#comment-80649). Don't suggest or infer a reason, just pause. Either the person asking the question will have a valid reason for doing so ("*HR wanted me to touch base on salary expectactions*"), or he'll be flustered and likely back-pedal.

If he can't explain a valid reason or you feel that you don't want to share that information now (or ever), say something like:

> I'd rather not go into that right now.
>
> I'm not sure that's relevant to our current discussion.
>
> I'd rather not share that information.
>
> I'm sorry but how is that relevant to Position X?

Again, just pause the conversation after one of these replies and let the uncomfortable silence build if necessary. Remember that if they push the topic, you are not being rude when you shut them down directly: they are being rude and crossing boundaries by pushing for an answer.

On the topic of salary: don't fall into [the trap of refusing to ever give a number first](http://www.askamanager.org/2012/04/when-a-candidate-wont-share-salary-expectations.html). It makes a bad impression and shows a lack of preparation. You need to know a range *before* your first interview.

Comment: Thanks for the link on the salary trap. An ultimate refusal to give a number or a salary range is just asking for trouble.

Comment: I have done numerous interviews on both sides of the table and have NEVER discussed salary.  That is left entirely to the hiring manager or HR

Answer (score 7):

> The question is, how not to answer the salary question, and any other out of scope topics, when the interview has a clear determined context?

## Don't make assumptions

I presume he is *not* who you'll be reporting to. Frequently interviewers are told not to discuss salary. It may be that HR does not actually want him to discuss this with you.

On the other hand, it may be that he was told to discuss salary with you. You might ask him if HR expects you to discuss it, and ask to double-check with HR as well.

## If you haven't verified that he is supposed to discuss salary

If you feel uncomfortable sharing that information, just say so: "I feel uncomfortable discussing that with you."

It would probably be prudent to explain that you intend to discuss that with the hiring manager or HR: "I intend to discuss that with the hiring manager and HR."